# How to read a character string from a pipe instead of a keyboard entry

Tags: windows, winapi, pipe, handle, anonymous

I have the following two C files from my textbook.

The first file is the parent process that is writing to the child process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 25

int main(void) {
    HANDLE ReadHandle, WriteHandle;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    char message[25] = "Hello";
    DWORD written;

    /* set up security attributes allowing pipes to be inherited */
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };

    /* allocate memory */
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    /* create the pipe */

    if (!CreatePipe(&ReadHandle, &WriteHandle, &sa, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Create Pipe Failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* establish the START INFO structure for the child process */
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    /* redirect standard input to the read end of the pipe */
    si.hStdInput = ReadHandle;


    /* don’t allow the child to inherit the write end of pipe */
    SetHandleInformation(WriteHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    /* create the child process */
    CreateProcess(NULL, filter(), NULL, NULL, TRUE,
        /* inherit handles */ 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    /* close the unused end of the pipe */
    CloseHandle(ReadHandle);

    /* the parent writes to the pipe */
    if (!WriteFile(WriteHandle, message, BUFFER_SIZE, &written, NULL))
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError writing to pipe abc .\n");

    /* close the write end of the pipe */
    CloseHandle(WriteHandle);

    /* wait for the child to exit */
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

And then for the child process:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 25

int filter() {
    HANDLE ReadHandle;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    //char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)* (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    //buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0'; 
    DWORD read;

    /* get the read handle of the pipe */
    //ReadHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    //SetHandleInformation(ReadHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    ReadHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    printf("Please work!!");

    /* the child reads from the pipe */
    if (ReadFile(ReadHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &read, NULL)) {
        //return buffer;
        printf("child read %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from pipe");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

When I run the parent process, I get child read (whatever I enter into the prompt) followed by a bunch of weird symbols (kind of looks like a row of `[][][][][]`). However, it seems like I should be receiving the message defined in the parent process instead. I have set `si.dwflags` to `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, which should allow my `si.hStdOutput` and `si.hStdInput` to not use the console, however it seems like it is still using the console input buffer for `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`.

Can anyone tell me why this is? How can I have a message sent through the pipe to my child process instead of a console input buffer?

Answer (score 0):

When `ReadFile()` exits, the `buffer` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.  You need to either:

1. add a null terminator before printing `buffer`:

   ```
   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+1]; // <-- add space for null terminator
   ...
   if (ReadFile(ReadHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &read, NULL)) {
       buffer[read] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
       printf("child read %s", buffer);
   }
   ```
2. take the `read` value outputted by `ReadFile()` into account when printing `buffer`:

   ```
   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // <-- null terminator not needed
   ...
   if (ReadFile(ReadHandle, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &read, NULL)) {
       printf("child read %.*s", read, buffer);
   }
   ```

Also note that you are closing the parent's pipe handles without waiting to make sure the child process actually finishes reading everything.  That might cause `ReadFile()` to fail, or at least return fewer bytes than requested.  So make sure you take that into account.  Either wait for the child process to exit before closing the parent's pipe handles, or make sure the child process handles partial data reads by calling `ReadFile()` in a loop until all expected bytes have been received.

Raymond Chen's MSDN blog also has some important information about reading/writing pipes across processes:

[Be careful when redirecting both a process's stdin and stdout to pipes, for you can easily deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx)

Comment: hey Remy, thanks for the response. The problem I have seems to be that the child is not receiving the message I defined in my parent file: char message[25] = "Hello";, instead it waits for the user to input a string into the console and then prints that out instead. It seems to me like the issue has to do with the StartupInfo struct.

Comment: Why are you using `GetStartupInfo()` to populate the `STARTUPINFO` that you used to start the child process?  `GetStartupInfo()` retreives the `STARTUPINFO` that was used to start the calling process, so it is not really appropriate for initializing a child process.  The parent process should create a new zero-initialized `STARTUPINFO` and populate only what it actually needs in it. Also, have you tried [MSDN's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx) yet? Get that working first, then customize it for your needs.